# Why is the text of a short tag excerpt getting trimmed on the Tags page view?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, tag-wiki-excerpt

On [the Tags page of Pets.SE](https://pets.stackexchange.com/tags), some of the tags are long and understandably they are trimmed for display (strangely from the front!).  There is at least one tag, "diet", which I think is short enough for display, but it's still getting trimmed.

Why is this happening?

Screen Capture:

[image]